# How to solve the error ""before all" hook: prepare suite:"

Tags: testing, ethereum, solidity, truffle

When I tested my contract, I got this error ""before all" hook: prepare suite:"

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

This is my dependencies.
"truffle": "5.0.7",
"web3": "1.0.0-beta.46"

Comment: Your question is better suited for https://ethereum.stackexchange.com

Comment: @IftifarTaz Thank you for your comment. I also posted there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm uninstall -g truffle

npm install -g truffle@5.1.10 (always got me back on track)

Answer (score 1):

Also, this issue occurs when used *several* test suites that use async test-helpers without **await** (for example, [OpenZeppelin Test Helpers: expectEvent, expectRevert](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/test-helpers/0.5/api)).

Consider example:

*contract*

```cs
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

contract Test03 {
    address public owner;
    int32 public id;

    event ContractCreated();

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;

        emit ContractCreated();
    }

    function doSmth(int32 _id) public {
        require(id != 0, "id is zero");
        id= _id;
    }
}
```

*test*

```js
const { expectEvent, expectRevert } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');

const TestContract = artifacts.require('Test03');

contract('Test03', function (accounts) {
    const [owner] = accounts;
    const txParams = { from: owner };

    beforeEach(async function () {
        this.testContract = await TestContract.new(txParams);
    });

    describe('construction', function () {
        it('initial state', async function () {
            expect(await this.testContract.owner()).to.equal(owner);

            // !! DONT FORGET await before expectEvent-call <<------------------------------
            await expectEvent.inConstruction(this.testContract, 'ContractCreated');
        });
    });

    describe('doSmth', function () {
      it('fail when passed zero id', async function () {

        // !! DONT FORGET await before expectRevert-call <<------------------------------
        await expectRevert(
          this.testContract.doSmth(0, txParams),
          "id is zero");
      });
  });    
});
```

*package.json*

```json
{
..
  "devDependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/test-helpers": "^0.5.10"
  }
..
}
```